# Matching ASP.NET MVC routes across /

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I know that when there is a route of the form

```
Alpha/Bravo/{Charlie}
```

and another of the form

```
Alpha/Bravo/Delta/{Echo}
```

the first route will match everything for both routes, because Delta/{Echo} is accepted as {Charlie}. Although this can be a pain when organizing routes, it can also be useful for the purpose of simplicity. I would like to be able to use this concept in the middle of a route string. I would like to make something like

```
Alpha/{Bravo}/Charlie
```

match URLs of the form

```
Alpha/bravo/Charlie
```

AND

```
Alpha/bravo/bravo2/Charlie
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression route. Something like the following could match the `{variant}` parameter with 1 or more trailing digits

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Title",
    "Controller/something/{variant}/Action",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" },
    new { variant = @"something\d+" }
);
```

Your route looks a little odd (maybe it's missing some curly braces), but my answer describes how you could use regular expressions for a number of parameters in your route.

With your exact route, Controller/something/{variant}/Action (again, this is odd), my mapped route would catch requests like:

```
/Controller/something/something123/Action
/Controller/something/something1/Action
```

But not

```
/Controller/something/somethingelse/Action
/Controller/something/nothing/Action
```

### Edit

If `{variant}` doesn't have a pattern, then I don't think you can use regular expressions. Otherwise, Routing wasn't designed like this.

If you want more than one parameter to be variable, use more than one reqular expression

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Title",
    "Controller/{something}/{variant}/Action",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" },
    new { variant = @"something\d+", something = @"(something|somethinglese)" }
);
```

If you need `{something}` to be optional, I can't quite remember, but you might need to move it to the last parameter and change the route to:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    "Title",
    "Controller/{variant}/Action/{something}",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", something = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { variant = @"something\d+", something = @"(something|somethinglese)" }
);
```

Comment: The problem is the parameter = "something" + vairant doesn't work. Since variant is not actually declared to exist anywhere, it doesn't, so it can't be added. What I need to do is grab the actual text that's there and append it to "something".

Comment: I edited my answer. If you're just modifying a parameter, why not just do it in the action method?

Comment: I would rather the action method just take in the one parameter and do it's job, which is quite simple and nicely coded already. I would like to handle the paramater before it.

Comment: edited the question with more information. I think it may have made it simpler...?

Comment: @Jim What are the possible values of `{variant]`?

Comment: Simple text words, occasionally including numbers at the end.

Comment: Would the routing match Controller/{Something}/Action to both of the routes in my question?

Comment: @Jim I suppose you could use multiple regular expressions, but you're really just compounding your problem. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, kinda rewrote the whole question. I think it's much clearer now

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a second route, so now I have

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Route1",
    "Alpha/{Bravo}/{Charlie}/Delta",
    new { controller = "Alpha", action = "Delta" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Route1",
    "Alpha/{Bravo}/Delta",
    new { controller = "Alpha", action = "Delta", Charlie = ""}
);
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Delta(string Bravo, string Charlie)
{
    Bravo += Charlie;
    //everything else
}
```

Everything works out now, although I would've like to have one route catch both cases.